# Is there any ritual to offer black chandan to Lord Hanuman or Bhairav?

Tags: shiva, hanuman

Recently I heard that black chandan is being offered to Lord Hanuman or Bhairav or both. Is it true?

Is there any ritual to offer black chandan to Lord Hanuman or Bhairav?

Comment: In case of Lord Hanuman we use to put sindhur to Hanuman. And sindhur is red, not black. Red is the color of Lord Hanuman. Black is not the color which is liked so much by Lord Hanuman. So we use red tilak for Lord Hanuman. And we even use to paste sindhur (red paste) to  his whole body. But Bhairav likes black so we use to do black tilak to Bhairav and as well as to ourselves when we do visit Bhairav's temple.